# Combine document ready with window resize

Tags: jquery, document-ready, window-resize

I have a script that runs a function on browser resize, but I also want it to run on document load. How do I combine (document).ready function with window resize function to get the script below to work?

```
var width = $(window).width();

 $(window).on('resize', function(){

 if ( width < 900 ) {

  } else {

   parallaxIt();

  } // End IF

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give yourself the function:

```
function handleResize() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 900) {
        // Presumably do something?
    } else {
        parallaxIt();
    }
}
```

And then use it as the callback for both `ready` and `resize`:

```
$(handleResize);
$(window).on('resize', handleResize);
```

Comment: that kind of worked except it didn't stop the function from running when below 900. Is this because I haven't told it to stop the function?

Comment: This did work, but I need to open a new question on how to remove a function.